# Solidity calling payable function with arguments with hardhat ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm testing this function:

```js
function Deposit(uint256 StopLoss) public payable {//Deposita quantity i es registre 
        
        //Pay subscription
        if (msg.value == 0){
            revert Quantity_zero();
        }
        //Add wallet to the s_Wallets
        s_Wallets.push(payable(msg.sender));
        //Start subscription time
        Dades storage dades = s_Registre[msg.sender];
        dades.Quantity += msg.value;
        dades.Stop = StopLoss;
    }
```

When sending value and StopLoss argument it allways send me some error.
This is the js testing code being 1850 the argument StopLoss value and sending a 5 ETH value.

```js
describe("Subscription", async function () {//PriceConversion
            it("Subscribes the deployer", async function () {

              await MarketOrder.Deposit(1850, {value: ethers.utils.parseEther("5")})

              const Quantity = await MarketOrder.CallQuantity()
              console.log(`Q: ${Quantity}`)
              const Stop = await MarketOrder.CallStop()
              console.log(`S: ${Stop}`)
              assert.equal(Quantity.toString(), 1850)
              assert.equal(Stop.toString(), 5)
            }
            })
```

This is the error:

```
1) MarketOrder Unit Tests
       Subscription
         Subscribes the deployer:
     Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=[1850], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.2)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:261:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:273:20)
      at Logger.throwArgumentError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:277:21)
      at Function.BigNumber.from (node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/src.ts/bignumber.ts:289:23)
      at NumberCoder.encode (node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/number.ts:25:27)
      at /home/oriok/hh-ff/1.uniswapV3/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/array.ts:71:19
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at pack (node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/array.ts:54:12)
      at TupleCoder.encode (node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/tuple.ts:54:20)
      at AbiCoder.encode (node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/abi-coder.ts:111:15)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Does anyone know how to send argument + value properly?? I have tryed many codes but not working.
Ty guys!

Answer (score 1):

ethers.utils.parseEther returns object with BigNumber in it..

you have to convert it into string before using it in the test..

Eg:

```
ethers.utils.parseEther("5").toString()
```

Refer..  https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseEther

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is showing me the same error.

`Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)`

Comment: Ok, fixed it. I had a problem with the next fuctions I was calling.